# Отображение картинки в WebView

Tags: android

Есть строка `<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/izvestnye/img1.jpg" alt="Image 1" /></p>`, которую я подаю на вход в WebView. Но прежде чем отобразить эту картинку я подставляю в ссылку домен сайта таким образом

```
if (img.contains("<img src=\"images")) {
    img = img.replaceAll("<img src=\"images", "<img src=\"https://site.ru/images");
}
```

Все работает.. Но вопрос такой можно ли отобразить картинку, независимо от протокола https или http? Или нельзя так сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы подаете в WebView саму страницу как строку, то ссылки на картинки и прочие не могут быть относительные. Только абсолютные.

Как альтернатива, картинки можно грузить из assets, пример:

```
String sHtmlTemplate = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\"file:///android_asset/my_pic.png\"></body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sHtmlTemplate, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

Соответственно, `my_pic.png` должен быть в `assets` в корне.

**Дополнено:**
Пришло в голову, сам никогда не пользовался, попробуйте так:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://site.ru/", myHtmlWithImg, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Этот же метод и предназначен для таких случаев, чтобы подставлять базу для относительных ссылок.

Comment: Спасибо, но такой подход не годится. Я с сайта гружу данные. Но спасибо за ответ.